# ¿Cómo pasar valores de parametros desde Ajax a metodo de controlador Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Nesecito pasar parametros desde Ajax a un metodo de mi controlador ... cuando lo invoco el metodo en mi controlador se ejecuta pero los parametros los recibe en null

Que sera lo que estoy haciendo mal ??

Ajax

```
 $('#ClientGroup').change(function () {
        var id = this.value;
        var id2 = '';
        console.log(`${id} ${id2}`);
        ClientGroupToClient(id,id2);
    });

    function ClientGroupToClient(id,id2) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Index",
            data: JSON.stringify({ IdClientGroupToClient: id, IdClientToRegional: id2 }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert(response.d);
         }
```

Codigo C#

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ActionName("Index")]
 public  ActionResult Index( string IdClientGroupToClient,string  IdClientToRegional )
        {
            string page = string.Empty;
            string dashboard = string.Empty;
            string   k = IdClientGroupToClient;
            return View();
}
```

Comment: Intenta pasar los parametros sin `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 2):

Si defines `contentType` como `json` deberias definir una clase como ser

```
public class ClientGroupModel {
    public string IdClientGroupToClient {get;set;}
    public string IdClientToRegional {get;set;}
}
```

de esta forma defines esta como parametro del action

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Index")]
public  ActionResult Index (ClientGroupModel model)
{
    //codigo
}
```

desde codigo cliente

```
function ClientGroupToClient(id,id2) 
{
    var datos = {
        IdClientGroupToClient: id,
        IdClientToRegional: id2 
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Index",
        data: datos,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
```

no deberias necesitar realizar el stringify

Answer (score 1):

Dado que estas usando jQuery para el data la sintaxis correcta deberia de ser:

```
data: "{IdClientGroupToClient:" + id + "IdClientToRegional:" + id2 + "}",
```

Comment: en realidad me funcion  quitando esta linea ....  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",